# Custom Circular Progress Bar Using React-Native (Without using any third party libraries)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

Hi I am designing a reporting page for my react-native app. I need to show a circular progress bar and an integer value (0-8) in the middle. I have tried multiple third parties libraries and I am getting similar errors in all of the SVG libraries. So, I want to build a custom circular bar using react-native components. I have already developed a code for it, but the circle is always filled to the full value. I want to change it to the percentage completion of the variable I am passing.
For instance, I passed 4 (the range of the variable is 0-8). So the circle should be 50% filled. But as per my code, it seems not to change at all and always appears full.
I am pasting my full code below and my current output as well.
Can someone please help me with this circle progress-filling issue?

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native';

const CircularProgressBar = ({ value }) => {
  const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * (100 / 2);
  const strokeDashoffset = new Animated.Value(circumference);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(strokeDashoffset, {
      toValue: (1 - value / 100) * circumference,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start();
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.circle}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.bar,
            {
              strokeDashoffset,
              strokeDasharray: `${circumference} ${circumference}`
            }
          ]}
        />
        <Text style={styles.text}>{value}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  circle: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 100,
    borderWidth: 20,
    borderColor: "#FF4433",
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  bar: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    borderColor: '#FFD580',
    borderWidth: 20,
    transform: [{ rotate: '-90deg' }],
    position: 'absolute'
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 43,
    color: '#FFD580'
    
  }
});

export default CircularProgressBar;
```

The output of this code looks like this

[image]